# Конструкция foreach удаление запятой у последнего элемента

Tags: foreach

Ребят нужно удалит запятую у последнего элемента, в идеале заменить на точку, подскажите может знает кто как это сделать?

```
<?php
                if (CFS()->get('musicBys') !='') {
    $musicBys = CFS()->get('musicBys');
    echo '<tr class="cored"><td class="movie-left-cell">' . __('Имя композитора или название группы, участвовавших в записи саундтрека: ', 'areview') . '</td><td>';
    foreach ($musicBys as $musicBy) {
    echo '<span itemprop="musicBy">'. esc_html($musicBy['musicBy']). '</span>, ';
    }
    echo '</td></tr>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Foreach{if($buf!=''){$buf.=',';}$buf.=$nextval;}$buf.='.';

Comment: `echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($musicBy) { return '<span itemprop="musicBy">'. esc_html($musicBy['musicBy']). '</span>'; }, $musicBys)) . '.';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    if(CFS()->get('musicBys') !='') {
        $musicBys = CFS()->get('musicBys');
        echo '<tr class="cored"><td class="movie-left-cell">' . __('Имя композитора или название группы, участвовавших в записи саундтрека: ', 'areview') . '</td><td>';
        $endChar = ".";
        $defChar = ",";
        foreach ($musicBys as $musicBy) {
            echo '<span itemprop="musicBy">'. esc_html($musicBy['musicBy']). '</span>'. $musicBy == end($musicBys) ? $endChar : $defChar;
        }
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
?>
```

попробуй так. Функция энд возращает последний элемент массива

UPD
если навичек то верхний код идентичен с нижнем. Они одинаковы но рекамендую верхний

```
<?

    php
        if(CFS()->get('musicBys') !='') {
            $musicBys = CFS()->get('musicBys');
            echo '<tr class="cored"><td class="movie-left-cell">' . __('Имя композитора или название группы, участвовавших в записи саундтрека: ', 'areview') . '</td><td>';
            $endChar = ".";
            $defChar = ",";
            foreach ($musicBys as $musicBy) {

                if ($musicBy == end($musicBys)) {
                    echo '<span itemprop="musicBy">'. esc_html($musicBy['musicBy']). '</span>'. $endChar;
                }
                else{
                    echo '<span itemprop="musicBy">'. esc_html($musicBy['musicBy']). '</span>'. $defChar;
                }
            }
            echo '</td></tr>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: нижний работает, а верхний только запятые выводит

Answer (score 0):

Простой способ. Вместо запятой используйте несолько (3,4,5 — по ситуации) пробелы. Вместо echo вначале сохраните результат в переменную строку. После цикла (foreach) выполните trim() (это удалит крайние пробелы), а после него эти множественный пробелы замените на нормальную запятую через str_replace('    ', ',', $s). В конце просто добавьте точку.

```
...

$str = '';

foreach ($musicBys as $musicBy) 
{
    $str .= '<span itemprop="musicBy">' . esc_html($musicBy['musicBy']) . '</span>     ';
}

$str = str_replace('     ', ', ', trim($str));

echo $str . '.';

...
```

Comment: не совсем понимаю как реализовать "сохраните результат в переменную строку"  можете подсказать?

Comment: добавил пример кода.